# Not signing in g+, in Type-A-Number Challenge game

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

I imported Type-A-Number Challenge game in to eclipse. I created leaderboard_id,achivements_id. I too checked sha1 used for creation of leaderboard and sha1 used for creation of apk file is same. I deleted project in Api console and recreated it with same sha1. But, when I click on sign in button in Type-A-Number Challenge game it is showing as "Sample not set correctly. See README ".

Answer (score 0):

Go to  the res/values/ids folder update the leaderboard_id and achivements_id in them which u got in developer console.